# Slicer wont connect to multiple pivot tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I have quite a few pivot tables (all connected to the same data source) however when I create a slicer and edit the pivot connections, it only shows one pivot table (the one I selected the slicer from.)

Note: The data they are all connected to is a named range.

Any idea how to fix this so I can connect the slicer to all of the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Try re-establishing all the data sources again.

Comment: Hi dwirony, is there any way to do that for all tables at once? I have over 20 in this workbook.

Comment: I'd start by just trying to re-establish it on two pivot tables first. Then when you create a slicer and check the connections, see if you're able to link those two tables. If that works, then I'd just go through each pivot table and manually change data sources.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data source to an Excel Table (aka ListObject) and then repoint the PivotTables to it. Named Ranges probably don't count as 'the same data source' from Excel's perspective, if the named range dimensions grow/shrink between the creation of one PivotTable and another. But Tables do.